# Unable to perform ajax api call

Tags: ajax, rest

My html page runs on the url specified below, from my html page i want to hit my rest api controller on a button click. But there is an error occuring since the api is not being called and the main spring boot application is getting started successfully on http port 8080.

**URL**

```
file:///C:/Users/PF077060/Downloads/project/project/UI%20design/html/Release.html
```

**Ajax Code:**

```
<script >
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        alert("AJAX request successfully completed");


        ajaxpost();
      });
      function ajaxpost()
      {
          console.log("formData1");  
          var formdata=
          {
                  name:$("#name").val(),
                inputcutoff:$("#inputcutoffdate").val(),
                releasedate:$("#releaseDate").val(),
                    status:$("#status").val(),                  
          };
          //alert("Changed into json format");
          console.log(formdata);
          $.ajax({
              type : "POST",
              contentType : "application/json", 
              url : "localhost:8080/" + "release/addrelease/",
              data : formdata,
              success : function(result)
              {
                alert(result.name);  
                window.location="Main.html";

              },
              error : function(e)
              {
                  alert("Error");
                  console.log("ERROR: ",e);
              }
         });
         resetdata();
      }
      function resetdata(){
          $("#name").val("");
          $("#inputcutoffdate").val("");
          $("#releaseDate").val("");
          $("#status ").val("");
      }
    });
</script>
```

**Error**

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'localhost:8080/release/addrelease/' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Read about CORS here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error was occurring because the CrossOrigin annotation wasn't specified in the controller class and the url in the Ajax call must start with http:localhost:8080 and so on.

```
**In the controllers**
@Crossorigin(origin="*")


**In the ajax call**
url: "http\localhost:8080\\{url were user want to get connected}"
```

Then the API shouldn't return a null value, the work of the API is to always process the information and should return some value to the client side. 
These were the changes which I made and my ajax call was also successful